# Is there python function to replace NaN values in time series?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two different time series, different size. And I want to replace the NaN values of the time series(1) with the last available value from the same month of time series(2). Is there a function that can do this?
Here is my time range:

```
timerange = pd.date_range('1/1/1', periods = 9, freq = 'D')
```

`d1_t` is my first time series:

```
d1_t = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(timerange)), timerange)
```

I'm going to add an Na:

```
d1_t['2001-01-03'] = np.nan
```

My second time_series is `d2_t`:

```
 d2_t = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(timerange)), timerange)
```

I want `d1_t['2001-01-03']`, that currently has NaN value, to be replaced by `d2_t['2001-01-02']`

Comment: We can use `fillna`  + `groupby.transform('last')`...Could you show an example of your Series?

Comment: So, lets say here is my time range: timerange = pd.date_range('1/1/1', periods = 9, freq = 'D'), d1_t is my first time series: d1_t = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(timerange)), timerange), I'm going to add an Na: d1_t['2001-01-03'] = np.nan, my second time_series is d2_t, d2_t = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(timerange)), timerange), I want d1_tt['2001-01-03'], that currently has NaN value, to be replaced by d2_t['2001-01-02']. Is that clear?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do what you want.  However, you need to provide a [mcve].  Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: please check my answer @Mahsem

Answer (score 2):

Use method fillna()

```
d1_t = d1_t.fillna(d2_t)
```

This will fill with data for the same day.

*I missed that the OP wanted to replace with data one day shifted. For this see @ansev's answer.*

Comment: Wellcome to stackoverflow!. He said: I want d1_t['2001-01-03'], that currently has NaN value, to be replaced by d2_t['2001-01-02'].
this would fill in with the corresponding value on the same day

Comment: Sorry, missed that. See @ansev answer using shift()

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) + [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html).
Only if the index of the series is exactly the same:

```
d1_t=d1_t.fillna(d2_t.shift())
print(d1_t)
2001-01-01    0.268759
2001-01-02   -0.064546
2001-01-03   -1.567730
2001-01-04   -0.770255
2001-01-05    0.479366
2001-01-06   -0.305752
2001-01-07    1.489243
2001-01-08    0.397007
2001-01-09    0.025405
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks ansev, I know my example includes two same length time series, but what if the time series are from different length? Is there a solution for that? @ansev

Comment: this really depends on how the series is exactly